# How to fix a javascript map pop up

Tags: javascript, jquery

We had a developer code this javascript map that has pop-ups when you hover over certain points.

http://www.cadenceaerospace.com/products/aeros/centers_of_excellence/index_test.html

I'm trying to add a new point (B&E) and it should open up the same way that Tell Tool opens up but I can't get it to work. I don't know much javascript so would someone be able to take a look and see what I'm doing wrong?

This is the code on the page that controls the map:

```
<script language="javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        $('#loc_map > DIV').css({'display': 'none', 'position': 'absolute'});
                        $('#loc_map > DIV > DIV').each(function(i,e) {
                            var close_button = document.createElement('span');
                            close_button.className = 'close_button';
                            var button_x = document.createElement('a');
                            button_x.innerHTML = 'X';
                            button_x.href = '#';
                            $(button_x).on('click', function(x) {
                                //console.log(e.parentNode.id);
                                $('#loc_map > DIV').css({'display': 'none'});
                                x.preventDefault();
                            });
                            $(close_button).prepend(button_x);
                            $(e).prepend( close_button );
                        });

                        $('#loc_map AREA')
                        .on('mouseover', function(e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            var div_id = e.currentTarget.alt,
                            div = $(document.getElementById(div_id)),
                            left = (div_id == 'tell_tool_operations')? e.pageX-5 - div.outerWidth() : e.pageX+5,
                            top = (RegExp(/^(giddens|pmw|tell|be)/).test(div_id))? e.pageY+5 : e.pageY-5 - div.outerHeight();
                            $('#loc_map > DIV').css({'display': 'none'});
                            div.css({'display': 'block', 'left': left, 'top': top});
                        }); 

                        $('#loc_map AREA')
                        .on('click', function(e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            var div_id = e.currentTarget.alt,
                            div = $(document.getElementById(div_id)),
                            left = (div_id == 'tell_tool_operations')? e.pageX-5 - div.outerWidth() : e.pageX+5,
                            top = (RegExp(/^(giddens|pmw|tell|be)/).test(div_id))? e.pageY+5 : e.pageY-5 - div.outerHeight();
                            $('#loc_map > DIV').css({'display': 'none'});
                            div.css({'display': 'block', 'left': left, 'top': top});
                        });
                    });
                </script>
```

Let me know if you need anything else from me. Thanks!

Comment: Check whether `div_id == 'be_oem'` as well to calculate `left`

Answer (score 0):

The line that calculates the left position needs to be modified from

```
left = (div_id == 'tell_tool_operations')? e.pageX-5 - div.outerWidth() : e.pageX + 5
```

...to...

```
left = (div_id == 'tell_tool_operations' || div_id == 'be_oem')? e.pageX-5 - div.outerWidth() : e.pageX + 5
```

The added part is `|| div_id == 'be_oem'`.

---

**Modified code**

```
<script language="javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        $('#loc_map > DIV').css({'display': 'none', 'position': 'absolute'});
                        $('#loc_map > DIV > DIV').each(function(i,e) {
                            var close_button = document.createElement('span');
                            close_button.className = 'close_button';
                            var button_x = document.createElement('a');
                            button_x.innerHTML = 'X';
                            button_x.href = '#';
                            $(button_x).on('click', function(x) {
                                //console.log(e.parentNode.id);
                                $('#loc_map > DIV').css({'display': 'none'});
                                x.preventDefault();
                            });
                            $(close_button).prepend(button_x);
                            $(e).prepend( close_button );
                        });

                        $('#loc_map AREA')
                        .on('mouseover', function(e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            var div_id = e.currentTarget.alt,
                            div = $(document.getElementById(div_id)),
                            left = (div_id == 'tell_tool_operations' || div_id == 'be_oem')? e.pageX-5 - div.outerWidth() : e.pageX+5,
                            top = (RegExp(/^(giddens|pmw|tell|be)/).test(div_id))? e.pageY+5 : e.pageY-5 - div.outerHeight();
                            $('#loc_map > DIV').css({'display': 'none'});
                            div.css({'display': 'block', 'left': left, 'top': top});
                        }); 

                        $('#loc_map AREA')
                        .on('click', function(e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            var div_id = e.currentTarget.alt,
                            div = $(document.getElementById(div_id)),
                            left = (div_id == 'tell_tool_operations' || div_id == 'be_oem')? e.pageX-5 - div.outerWidth() : e.pageX+5,
                            top = (RegExp(/^(giddens|pmw|tell|be)/).test(div_id))? e.pageY+5 : e.pageY-5 - div.outerHeight();
                            $('#loc_map > DIV').css({'display': 'none'});
                            div.css({'display': 'block', 'left': left, 'top': top});
                        });
                    });
                </script>
```